Faster algorithm for maximum-weighted convolution
I am implementing an algorithm from a paper titled "Adaptive Multi-Trace Carving Based on Dynamic Programming." Specifically, this algorithm requires solving the following:
$$
y[n] = \max_{k \in [0, N)} \{ x[k] \cdot h[n - k] \}
$$
In this equation，x[n] and h[n] are known, and y[n] needs to be computed for n from 0 to N. This operation resembles convolution, except that it uses the MAX operation instead of SUM.
Is there any way to compute y[n] in O(NlogN) time complexity?
Any insights would be appreciated.

Taking logarithm turns this formula into an actual convolution in the max-plus tropical semiring. I'm not sure if it'd help to speed up things though.
